# How to concat several video clips with different property using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video, concatenation

I want to concat several videos using ffmpeg.
I have 1.mp4 2.mp4 3.mp4 files
I used this command

```
ffmpeg -y -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -i 3.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=0:10,scale=1920:1080,setsar=1[v0];[1]trim=0:10,scale=1920:1080,setsar=1[v1];[2:v]trim=0:10,scale=1920:1080,setsar=1[v2];[v0][v1][v2]concat=n=3:v=1[outv]" -map "[outv]" -g 12 -c:v libx264 output.mp4
```

I expected the output.mp4 to be 30 seconds but it was 20 seconds long and the third video wasn't concatenated correctly.

If I try to concat using the same video like this

```
ffmpeg -y -i 1.mp4 -i 1.mp4 -i 1.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=0:10,scale=1920:1080,setsar=1[v0];[1]trim=0:10,scale=1920:1080,setsar=1[v1];[2:v]trim=0:10,scale=1920:1080,setsar=1[v2];[v0][v1][v2]concat=n=3:v=1[outv]" -map "[outv]" -g 12 -c:v libx264 output.mp4
```

It worked.

Please help me solve this.
Thanks